# listview doesn't update on the second time only

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a listview in WPF that doesn't add the second row until a third row is added and then all three render. Each next row renders correctly and immediately.
I don't really have a clue on why this happens only on the second time.

wpf code:

```
          <ListView Name="DownloadList" Background="WhiteSmoke" PreviewMouseRightButtonUp="DownloadList_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp" >
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="60" Header="Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FormattedSize}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Speed" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FormattedSpeed}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="170" Header="Progress">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ProgressBar Height="20" Width="150" Maximum="{Binding Size}" Value="{Binding Progress}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="65" Header="Time Left" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FormattedTime}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="60" Header="Peers" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Peers}"/>          
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

behind code:

```
        FileDownload download = new FileDownload(fileToDownload.id, fileToDownload.DownloadName,(int)fileToDownload.Length, partsData.Length);
        wpfDownloads.Add(download);
```

Comment: need more code to be sure, but this sounds like a symptom of calling your code in a loop on the UI thread, and I am guessing you are testing with 3 items, and it updates only when this loop exits.  Are you downloading in a background thread, task (TPL), or using the dispatcher?

Comment: @Kory Gill the download is in a background thread. The code that adds a new row to the table only runs when the download command is initiated. Note that if I add a fourth or a fifth item they are added instantly. This is only for the second row. Also, I now checked and you can see that the listview becomes longer (there is an 'invisible' row)